# Getting data from CSV for a specific date and time in python

Tags: python, csv

I have written a python program which gets csv data for a specific date in python. I want to also get the data for a specific time like for 2 hours on a specific date. But the problem is that in my csv file, date and time are stored in different columns (col 2 for time).I also want to plot the data for this on a graph. heres my code:

```
 from_raw = self.userInputFromRaw.get()
    from_date = datetime.date(*map(int, from_raw.split('/')))
    print ('From date: = ' + str(from_date))
    to_raw = self.userInputToRaw.get()
    to_date = datetime.date(*map(int, to_raw.split('/')))
    in_file = 'C:\\Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\ARIF Drop Monitoring Final\ARIF Drop Monitoring Final\DataLog.CSV'
    in_file= csv.reader(open(in_file,"r"))

    for line in in_file:
        _dist = line[0]
        try:
            file_date =  datetime.date(*map(int, line[1].split(' ')[1].split('/')))
            if from_date <= file_date <= to_date:
                self.CsvImport(in_file)

        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Can anyone tell me how can i get data for a specific time interval on a specific date (taken by the user) and plot it on a graph? I dont know how can i extract for BOTH date and time simultaneously.

my Csv file looks like this:

```
2    2017/02/17  23:02:31.615
1    2017/02/17  23:02:36.611
1    2017/02/17  23:02:41.601
2    2017/02/17  23:02:46.748
2    2017/02/17  23:02:51.620
2    2017/02/17  23:02:56.627
1    2017/02/17  23:03:01.617
2    2017/02/17  23:03:06.646
2    2017/02/17  23:03:11.643
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exact issues you are facing in your code? Provide any error messages you are receiving. If your code runs but provides invalid output, then please provide a sample input with the output you are getting. Also, provide an expected output. Ensure you have put together your question to meet the requirements of a good [mcve]

Comment: Why are you parsing manually AND using a csv reader? Can you also show some sample lines from your data?

Comment: this is a function which takes the date and then extracts the data from the csv file which looks like this:                                                                        2  2017/02/17  23:02:31.615                                                                  I want to take the date and time from the user and then extract data according to that. I dont know how can i do it for the time AND time at the same time.

Comment: edit your question to add the info instead of commenting

Comment: i have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the pandas module to handle pretty much everything here. Here's what I'd do.

### Sample data

```
2    2017/02/17  23:02:31.615
1    2017/02/17  23:02:36.611
1    2017/02/17  23:02:41.601
2    2017/02/17  23:02:46.748
2    2017/02/17  23:02:51.620
2    2017/02/17  23:02:56.627
1    2017/02/17  23:03:01.617
2    2017/02/17  23:03:06.646
2    2017/02/17  23:03:11.643
```

### The code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "dat.csv"
# arguements for pandas.read_csv
kwargs = {
    "sep": "\s+", # specifices that it's a space separeted file
    "names": ["value", "date", "time"], # names the columns
    "parse_dates": [[1,2]], # combine columns 2 and 3 into a datetime col
    "index_col": "date_time", # set the datetime column as the index
    }
# read the csv into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(filename, **kwargs)
# select a certain range of times
# pandas is smart about slicing date ranges out of a datetime index
# just write out a slice like below using a standard datetime format
# and pandas will figure out what you want. Convenient.
df = df["2017-02-17 23:02:31":"2017-02-17 23:02:51"]
# plot it using pandas built in wrapper for matplotlib.pyplot
df.plot()
# show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: what if your file is very large?  is there a good solution with chunking?